# Cannot get MongoDB Store to work with PassportJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am a beginner with Node.JS and Express but I have managed to create a fully-functional web-app. I noticed that when going to production mode, I was storing sessions in the RAM. Instead, I would like to store them in a Mongo Store.

Since I am working with Passport, I would like to know how to get serialize and deserialize functions to work with the Mongo Store. It seems to work well to store the session (I see it in the database), but I can't fetch it.

**More precisely, I would like to know how to retrieve the session ID to fetch the user from the database.**

Here is my server code:

```
var store = new MongoDBStore(
      {
        uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
        mongooseConnection: db,
        collection: 'mySessions'
      });

    // Catch errors 
    store.on('error', function(error) {
      throw error;
    });

app.use(session({
    secret: '****',
    resave: true,
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000}
    }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        var user = new User();

        var profileUser = user.extractProfile(profile);

        done(null, profileUser.email); // The only info I need is the user email address

  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('Serializing user:'+user); // user returns the email address
    done(null, user); // The session is stored
});

var Sessions = db.collection('mySessions');

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

    console.log('Deserializing user:'+id); // What clearly doesn't work here, is that I'm trying to fetch a document using the email address instead of the "_id"...

    return Sessions.findOne({ user: id }, function (error, user) {
        console.log('Found :');
        console.log(user);
        return done(error, user);
    });
});
```

Here is one entry in the Mongo Store:

```
   {
    "_id": "10yEo3rU4Qumf2jw3346UtY0cCnRWNhc",
    "session": {
        "cookie": {
            "originalMaxAge": 604800000,
            "expires": {
                "$date": "2017-02-25T13:46:57.231Z"
            },
            "secure": null,
            "httpOnly": true,
            "domain": null,
            "path": "/",
            "sameSite": null
        },
        "passport": {
            "user": "le*****@*****.com"
        }
    },
    "expires": {
        "$date": "2017-02-25T13:46:57.231Z"
    }
}
```

I believe that if I was able to make the deserialize function work properly, everything would work like before. Any ideas on how to do that?

**(edit)** I edited the deserialize function to do a manual search on my session ID (I got the ID from the Mondo database), like this:

```
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

    console.log('Deserializing user:'+id);
    return Sessions.findOne({ _id: 'faogaErvZirU2lVpo49M-Bkz7zuQwbhP' }, function (error, user) {
        console.log('Found :');
        console.log(user);
        return done(error, user.session.passport.user);
    });
});
```

And *it works*. So, unless I'm mistaken, the only thing I need to figure out is how to get the _id from the cookie, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours looking for an answer, I checked similar projects on GitHub and more precisely, successful integration of Passport alongside with stored sessions.

I figured out my problem: I needed to store my users, not their sessions (the Mongo Store was already doing that). Therefore, I changed my Google Strategy to create a new user in the database OR retrieve its profile:

```
var UserDB = db.collection('users');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {

    UserDB.findOne({ 'id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {

         var newUser = {};
         newUser.id = profile.id;
         newUser.token = token;
         newUser.name = profile.displayName;
         newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;            
         UserDB.insert({ 'id': profile.id, 'token': token, 'name': profile.displayName , 'email': profile.emails[0].value}, function (err) {
               if (err) {
                  throw err;
               }
               return done(null, newUser);
        });
    }
  });
});
}));
```

From there on, I just had to look up the user in the database:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {

    return UserDB.findOne({ id: user.id }, function (error, user) {

        return done(error, user);
    });
});
```

My mistake was thinking that serializeUser and deserializeUser were all about sessions, when in reality it was all about user profiles. The sessions were managed 100% by Express-session and MongoDB Store, so I didn't need to worry about them.

Comment: What is MongoDBStore? I see a few references to MongoStore, but I can't get that to work at all. I can find no other references to MongoDBStore other than this post. What npm package is required for that?